# Como realizar uma consulta de uma query armazenada numa string através da classe DB?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Queria a conversão dessa query como poderiar usa-la no DB \ Facades do Lavarel

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET(KillCount, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(KillCount ORDER BY KillCount DESC) FROM users)) AS Rank FROM users WHERE id = 1
```

Ela pega o rank position do jogador pela ordem de Kills de todo o servidor.

## Atualização

Ao usar o `whereRaw`, como foi sugerido, ocorre o seguinte erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pois antes ele faz a montagem do `SELECT *`

Comment: Boa tarde, jovem. Poderia copiar o código do erro gerado e postar aqui, para podermos formatá-lo de maneira mais apropriada?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o método `DB::select` diretamente. Ele permite que você execute uma query a partir de uma string.

Veja:

```
$query = 'SELECT FIND_IN_SET(KillCount, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(KillCount ORDER BY KillCount DESC) FROM users)) AS Rank FROM users WHERE id = 1';

$resultado = DB::select($query);
```

Comment: Nesses casos eu costumo usar muito quando eu preciso debugar alguma coisa através do `SHOW TABLES`.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o método `whereRaw()` da Facade, ficaria algo parecido com isto:

```
\DB::table("users")->whereRaw("FIND_IN_SET(KillCount, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(KillCount ORDER BY KillCount DESC) FROM users)) AS Rank")
       ->where('id', 1)
       ->get();
```

Comment: De acordo com o comentário do Autor da Pergunta, sua resposta faz gerar um erro.

Comment: Realmente @WallaceMaxters, na hora eu não consegui testar e agora testei e vi que estava errado.